# How to get the 3 collections array values from mongo db and displayed in table in angular js

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have 3 collections with different categories:

```
[{
   "customerToken" : "wagonsoft", 
   "category" : "job", 
   "questions" : [
       {
           "questionOrder" : "", 
           "jobName" : "Associate software engineer", 
           "departmentName" : "", 
           "questionType" : "yes OR no", 
           "question" : "some queston?", 
           "answers" : "", 
           "justification" : "yes", 
           "mandatory" : true
       },
       {
           "questionOrder" : "", 
           "jobName" : "Associate software engineer", 
           "departmentName" : "", 
           "questionType" : "yes OR no", 
           "question" : "some queston?", 
           "answers" : "", 
           "justification" : "yes", 
           "mandatory" : true
       }
    ]
}, {
   "customerToken" : "wagonsoft", 
   "category" : "department", 
   "questions" : [
       {
           "questionOrder" : "", 
           "jobName" : "Associate software engineer", 
           "departmentName" : "", 
           "questionType" : "yes OR no", 
           "question" : "some queston?", 
           "answers" : "", 
           "justification" : "yes", 
           "mandatory" : true
       }, 
       {
           "questionOrder" : "", 
           "jobName" : "Associate software engineer", 
           "departmentName" : "", 
           "questionType" : "yes OR no", 
           "question" : "some queston?", 
           "answers" : "", 
           "justification" : "yes", 
           "mandatory" : true
       }
    ]
}, {
   "customerToken" : "wagonsoft", 
   "category" : "company", 
   "questions" : [
       {
           "questionOrder" : "", 
           "jobName" : "Associate software engineer", 
           "departmentName" : "", 
           "questionType" : "yes OR no", 
           "question" : "some queston?", 
           "answers" : "", 
           "justification" : "yes", 
           "mandatory" : true
       },
       {
           "questionOrder" : "", 
           "jobName" : "Associate software engineer", 
           "departmentName" : "", 
           "questionType" : "yes OR no", 
           "question" : "some queston?", 
           "answers" : "", 
           "justification" : "yes", 
           "mandatory" : true
       },
    ] 
}]
```

These are in the database but how can I retrieve it from database and how do I display in one table, can any of you please help?

Comment: I think you mean you have three different document type in one collection !? ;).

Comment: Make http request, load data, render with ngRepeat. Very easy. Broad answer to broad question.

Comment: Yes i  have 3 categories  documents in  one collection could you help me how to get from database